# Covid Vacination status of an Indian going to France

Tags: france, covid-19

I have been going to France from India and I am an Indian citizen and I have been vacinated with 2 doses of Covishield.

Is this number of vaccines sufficient for going to France?

Comment: Does https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coming-to-france-your-covid-19-questions-answered/ answer your question? Have you researched this at all? Incidentally, this question would seem more relevant on https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Relaxed I searched it but I couldn't find this page. I am really sorry for any inconvinence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this number of vaccines sufficient for going to France?

Depending on the date your received the second shot, it might not have been enough to be considered “vaccinated” under the rules in place until August, 1st but currently there is no vaccination requirement whatsoever.